# How to inject the default Guice Provider into my custom Provider?

Tags: dependency-injection, guice

If I create a provider and bind it to a class, like this

```
bind(MyClass.class).toProvider(MyClassProvider.class)
```

then `Provider<MyClass>` automatically be bound `to MyClassProvider`. That's a problem if you want to inject a `Provider<MyClass>` into `MyClassProvider`, like this:

```
@Inject
public MyClassProvider(Provider<MyClass> provider)
```

I want to inject the default Guice provider into my provider so I can easily create new instances inside my custom provider. How to do that?

Comment: Why do you want to do this ? MyClassProvider will do provider.get() instead of new MyClass() ?

Comment: I want to do this because the constructor of MyClass is not so simple -- it has other injected dependencies, which in turn have dependencies. Second reason is that Actually I am writing a generic provider, which I want to use for many actual class like this: bind(MyClass.class).toProvider(new TypeLiteral<MyProvider<MyClass>>() {});

Comment: Ok for the first reason. What does this generic provider will do ? May be, there are other solutions.

Comment: The generic providers routes the requested Class to a specific cached instance. (The routing is based on a header in the HTTP request and the returned instance is specific to a backend instance) I think it could be implemented somehow using a custom Guice scope, but I think it would be a magnituder harder.

Comment: Basically if the labeled backend indicated in the HTTP request has been created before, I return the cached instance that I have built before. If this is the first time, I create the whole object graph using default provider of guice. My DB connection provider of course checks again which backend to connect based on the HTTP request. The whole point that I don't have to build the whole object graph at every request, but only if I connect to a certain backend for the first time. So what I want is something like a 'named Singleton'. (The names are based on the http requests)

Comment: Ok, i would propose a solution based on scope.

Comment: I posted a question related to your proposal: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15556802

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use a [binding annotation](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations) on one of the two. If you don't mind the users of MyClass being annotated it is quite easy.

```
public class AccountTest {

   @Test
   public void test() {
       Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {

           @Override
           protected void configure() {
               bind(MyClass.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("MYPROVIDER")).toProvider(MyClassProvider.class);
           }
       });
       MyClassUser user = injector.getInstance(MyClassUser.class);

       assertTrue(user.get().myProvider); // Shows if was created via my provider or the Guice provider.
   }
}

class MyClassUser {
    Provider<MyClass> provider;

    @com.google.inject.Inject
    public MyClassUser(@Named("MYPROVIDER") Provider<MyClass> provider) {
        this.provider=  provider;
    }

    MyClass get() {
        return provider.get();
    }
}

class MyClass {
    boolean myProvider = false;
}

class MyClassProvider implements Provider<MyClass> {
    Provider<MyClass> provider;

    @com.google.inject.Inject
    public MyClassProvider(Provider<MyClass> provider) {
        this.provider=  provider;
    }

    @Override
    public MyClass get() {
        MyClass c = provider.get();
        c.myProvider = true;
        return c;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Our provider";
    }
}
```

If you don't want the users of MyClass to use a named provider the only way I've been able to get it to work was to extend `MyClass` and have `MyClassProvider` require a "`MyClass2`" Provider. As a solution it smells, but worked (rather than pollute this answer with a bad answer, you can find the code on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mlk/5220259)).

You may be able to do this with with private modules or child modules (as it is a variant on the Robot Legs problem) but I've been unable to work out how to do this.